# Какой вариант решения задачи лучше? И какой еще вариант можете предложить?

Tags: jquery, javascript

1)select имеет name = occup_pr[];
2)option имеет два варианта: маг и воин.
3)цель была такова: если выбран маг,то показывается скрытая часть элемента.

1 Вариант кода(мне кажется он более упрощенный).

```
 $('select').change(function(){
 var opt = $("select[name='occup_pr[]']").val();
 if (opt == 'Маг'){
 $("fieldset#protagonist_occupation").show();
 }
 else if(opt == 'Воин'){
 $("fieldset#protagonist_occupation").hide();
 }
 });
```

2 Вариант кода. Тут я произвел разбор через each.

```
$("select[name='occup_pr[]']").change(function(){
     $("select[name='occup_pr[]'] option:selected").each(function () {
     var opt = $(this).attr('id');
     if (opt == 'occup_pr_t1'){
     $("fieldset#protagonist_occupation").show();
     }
     else if(opt == 'occup_pr_t2'){
     $("fieldset#protagonist_occupation").hide();
     }
     })
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вариант вполне нормальный. Можно сделать небольшие изменения для удобочитаемости:

```
$('select[name="occup_pr[]"]').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val(),
        $elem = $('#protagonist_occupation');
    if (value == 'Маг') {
        $elem.show();
    } else {
        $elem.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: @andreyqin, лучше закинуть элемент в переменную за пределами обработки события, чем каждый раз, когда это событие будет происходить:

    $elem = $('#protagonist_occupation');
    $('select[name="occup_pr[]"]').on('change', function() {
        $elem[$(this).val() == 'Маг' ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
    });

Comment: Кстати, тоже об этом подумал. Но с другой стороны - выборка по id очень быстрая.